# Why do fundamentals matter?

Tags: research-process, learning

In certain situations, fundamentals may not matter, but very often, especially for long term learning, they really matter. Since this is a deeply held belief, perhaps moulded by experience, I find it tricky to articulate to an intelligent skeptic why they should bother learning fundamentals. They often have surprisingly strong rebuttals, including:

> experts do not find such basic material interesting

I empathise: if someone in a specific niche is getting along just fine without understanding fundamentals, they may have no motivation to learn fundamentals, especially if they're already recognised as an expert (not *necessarily* by peers, but perhaps by students, clients, or consumers of their research).

#### Question

What lines of reasoning or resources (preferably canonical ones) do you use to demonstrate the value of fundamentals to those who may be sceptical of the value in learning them?

#### One Example

This happens to be from a physicist, [Richard Feynman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqp3KXDu9qE):

> In physics, when you discover new things, it looks more simple

> (when) We learn about a greater experience .. the laws look complicated ... but .. every now and then we have these integrations .. (and) it turns out to be simpler that it looked before

The corollary being that when we understand something on a fundamental level, it's actually much easier to communicate, understand, model and predict.

Comment: Can you give an example of a "fundamental" whose pedagogical value you doubt?

Comment: @cag51 I don't doubt, but frequently see cases where someone doesn't see value in fundamentals. Some quick, specific examples (others may have some much better ones). In software, when someone needs to get something working quickly, copying code from stack overflow and running it without any understanding of what it's doing. In biology, racing to research a topical and easy (or "sexy") area of research, while neglecting more fundamental areas which may be more difficult but of much greater importance (that's subjective, I know). Economic principles which seem so simple they're not scrutinised.

Comment: "if someone in a specific niche is getting along just fine without understanding fundamentals" What a strange premise. They might believe they are getting along fine but they actually aren't. This paper is a great example of not knowing undergrad fundamentals: https://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/17/2/152.abstract Personally, I'd rather try not to be embarrassed like that. "[E]xperts do not find such basic material interesting" Of course not. In order to become an expert, you need to master the basics. Once you have mastered them, they are not terribly interesting.

Comment: @Roland I'd have said that was A-level, rather than undergraduate, mathematics.  Nevertheless, I'd imagine the authors' embarrassment is somewhat moderated by having a paper with 436 citations.

Comment: @Roland I think papers like the one you point out are actually more common than is realised. And even more common in research that isn't thoroughly peer reviewed (e.g. some government or private sector research). I'm not sure if you intended to, but you provided an answer: to avoid embarrassment. That's pretty funny, and brutal, and actually the best answer I have so far. But then the problem is what if the party without the understanding of fundamentals is simply not at all embarrassed? What other reasoning or appeals can or should be made?

Comment: @Roland: Hmm, I'd argue that rather than the paper itself, its considerable number of citations (which has also been mentioned by @DanielHatton) provides strong evidence of a general lack of "understanding the fundamentals".

Comment: @JochenGlueck but how many of those citations are from papers pointing out the mistake or using it as an example of lack of understanding?

Comment: @stevec - Could you give one concrete example that applies to your question? Your examples in the comment above are quite vague.

Comment: @astronat The first three in Google Scholar's "cited by" list are all papers using the method and citing Tai's paper as the sole source for it.  I stopped checking after that because I don't have full-text access to the fourth.

Comment: A left-field thought, though: the trapezium rule was first proposed before the invention of peer review, so it's possible that Tai's paper really was the first peer-reviewed paper to give a full description of the method.  A bit like Osborne Reynolds' discovery that ice is slippery.

Comment: @astronat: Ah, sorry - I just noted that I forgot to reply to your comment. (Fortunately, it seems tha DanielHatton has already replied instead of me. ;-) )

Comment: You can't read Shakespeare without knowing the alphabet, but that doesn't mean you find the alphabet very interesting.

Comment: @Andrew but is finding something uninteresting grounds for excluding it from research or learning? I have experienced it being used as an excuse for avoidance of fundamentals. i thought creating the case *for* fundamentals to be very easy, until I actually went to do it. I believed in fundamentals almost as through it were religion! So I seek evidence or canon that supports learning fundamentals, and most importantly, explains why it is important. A good example I stumbled upon 2 days ago was Principia Mathematica spending some ~200 pages to prove that 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: Hm. Well, it depends a bit on exactly what you mean, this is a bit too abstract for me to understand. You certainly can fall into a trap of getting lost in the weeds and not getting anything done. The 200 pages were not really there to prove 1+1=2 -- as I recall in the book that theorem has a note like "this is a relatively unimportant result we prove due to historical interest" -- but to build this logical edifice which was the main goal. If your goal is not to build a logical edifice for all math, spending 200 pages on 1+1=2 is probably a waste of time.

Comment: Also famously the logical edifice of the Principia Mathematica doesn't work in the way the authors intended, due to Godel's incompleteness theorem. So... your mileage may vary :D